# What should the format of tags be for different Joomla! versions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think for these specific tags it might be better to come up with an agreed upon format rather than let everyone come up with it on the fly. Some quick examples being `Joomla! 2`, `Joomla 2.5.x`, `J3`, `2.5.x`, `j2.5`, `j2.5.x`, `joomla 3`.

Comment: Since the site is all about Joomla, should we go a more general approach and use something like `v2.5` or `version 2.5`. Though I can see where we might have to distinguish between CMS versions and Framework versions too...

Comment: @DavidFritsch Good point. I hadn't though about distinguishing between CMS and Framework versions.

Comment: I think we'll need a minimum of the following to start with: v1.0, v1.5, v1.6, v1.7, v2.5, v3.x

Comment: I am for @NeilRobertson approach

Comment: I second @NeilRobertson's approach, but maybe we should use 'cms' instead of the 'v' to differentiate between cms and framework later

Comment: I like the short version of @NeilRobertson too but a prefix for cms and framework like cms-3.2 and fw-1.0 would be more clear in the future.

Comment: Good catch @HaraldLeithner

Comment: @HaraldLeithner That's looking good

Answer (score 5):

I will try to form an answer that we could use in the help page...

Suggested version tags

- cms-1.0
- cms-1.5
- cms-1.6
- cms-1.7
- cms-2.5
- cms-3.x
- cms-3.1
- cms-3.2
- cms-3.3
- cms-3.4
- cms-3.5
- fw-1.0

For mysql and compatible sql servers like mariaDB or Percona Server
 - mysql-5.0
 - mysql-5.1
 - ...

- postgres-9.0
- postgres-9.1
- ...
- mssql-
- ...

For Apache
 - apache-2.2
 - apache-2.4

For PHP
 - php-5.3
 - php-5.4
 - ...

and so on... a little bit pointless to write this down ;-)

the better question is should this be enforced or should synonyms be used?

Comment: Edit: I'm a dullard.  I was saying something about hyphens but it looks like they're required to tie the tag together.  Shame. So this looks good! :)

Comment: This is good but I don't think we gain anything by making people break down stack versions. I think simply having `PHP` or `MYSQL` will make those tags much more useful.

Comment: Maybe true, it shouldn't be to complicated

Comment: @ToniMarie It's funny you mention the hyphen. I would remove it too.

Comment: I think we should have at least the cms- and fw- tags. Maybe more tags (for MySQL, PHP,...) are too complicated.

Comment: @fl0r I agree with you

Comment: Would jfw be better than fw? I've seen a few framework questions that are not talking about the joomla framework.

Comment: The issue with this `cms-2.5` & co. tags are that they are also used for SEO. And `cms-2.5` has no SEO value, as anybody will search for Joomla 2.5. It will appear in the title of each question.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like:

- joomla1.5
- joomla2.5 (as a synonym for joomla1.6, joomla1.7)
- joomla3.x (as a synonym for joomla3.0, joomla3.1, joomla3.2)
- framework1.x (as a synonym for framework1.0, framework1.1 etc.)

Comment: joomla1.5 doesn't say anything because it a year there is maybe a joomla framework 1.5 version. Personally I like short and structured tags (a separator between a word and a number)

Comment: Well, at this point in time Joomla is better known for the CMS, not the framework, so while your comment is fair, it will come more handy this way, I think.

Comment: I think you both have valid points. I would use the shortened tag though, but clearly differentiate between the framework and the cms. If we used suggested tags, when someone types joomla we could perhaps show the shortened cms tag.

Answer (score 0):

Using J1.5 and J15 on the forum. Suggest to use FW1 for Framework, would have preferred F1 but that is easily confused with function keys. Suggest to use no - or . in the numbers. Not sure there needs to be more than: J25, J3 and J4 for the CMS. Can't say anything about framework or with the future packages. Not enough information available on that.

Comment: And what about JIssues?